# is or has a reddish brown color?

Tags: verbs

I'm wondering whether "is" or "has" should be used in the following sentence.

> The horse is/has a reddish brown color.

And I'm curious about whether we could say "John is a younger age" or "The car is a lower price."

Comment: Is there any difference?

Comment: And I'm curious about whether we could say "John is a younger age" or "The car is a lower price."

Answer (score 1):

Both are idiomatic and in most contexts would mean the same thing.

The difference between "*is*" and "*has*" is that "is" normally refers to something *in its entirety*. For example, "*the car is red*" would describe a car that is entirely red. When we say something *has* a particular attribute, it may not be the only attribute it possesses.

With colour, there are some unusual idioms. We might say someone *is* blonde, meaning their hair is blonde. We could also say they "have blonde hair". Also, we might say that a car "is red with black trim", which means that it *is* red, but not entirely.

With your other example of age, the way you phrase it means either word could work. In English, we tend to describe age by saying someone "is" a particular age (eg "John is 21" or "John is 21 years old"). We don't say that someone "has [x] years" like some other languages do. But we *can* say that someone "has" a particular age, as well as saying that they *are* that age.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the color, I believe either is correct.  But a native would speaker would not say "The horse has reddish-brown color".   In fact, since "color is implied, by the adjective, normally it would be "The horse is reddish-brown" (and not "has").  Sometimes a person might add the qualifier, such as "The horse is gray in color" (to be clear we're not talking about the AGE of the horse).

As to the others:
"John is a younger age" -- OK, but I think normally:  "John is younger", if comparing, but if not "John is young".  Your original might be used in an unusual context:  "Jim was getting to that age when boys think about the future.  But John is a younger age."

"The car is a lower price" -- I don't see anything wrong with that.  On it's own, I think it's an odd sentence -- lower than what?   If there is not another car the conversation, it would probably be "This car has a low price.", or "This is a low-priced car."